# how to mapping Long to column datetime

Tags: hibernate

my column type is datetime

```
`firstExpressTime` datetime NOT NULL ,
```

and my property is Long
i use

```
@Column(nullable=false)
private Long firstExpressTime;
```

but when i save the entity,it report excpetion

> ```
> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '1415945797963' for column 'firstExpressTime' at row 1
> ```

how to solve it? thanks for your any help and suggestion at advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since on the database you use datetime you will need to use java.util.Date in your Java / Hibernate code.

However, I believe this should not be too much of a problem since you can get the underlying timestamp anytime by calling getTime()

```
DbHibernateObj obj = service.getMyObject(id);
long timestamp = obj.getFirstExpressTime().getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use AttributeConverter. Annotate your Long field like that:

```
@Convert(converter = DateToLongConverter.class)
    private Long birthdate;
```

and create your converter class:

```
@Converter
public class DateToLongConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(Long attribute) {
        return new Date(attribute);
    }

    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(Date dbData) {
        return dbData.getTime();
    }
}
```